# Boost::log stdout is displayed only after execution when called from bash script

Tags: php, c++, bash, stdout, fwrite

I'm running a php file on a webserver, which executes a bash script. The stdout of the script should be streamed to a file, such that the client can fetch and display it.

The script `myscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "-- starting --"
EXE="/home/username/mybinary"
ARGS="/home/username/config.cfg"
PRE="sudo"
$PRE $EXE $ARGS
echo "-- finished --"
```

The calling php:

```
$fplog = fopen("../bin/log.txt", "w");
if( ($fp = popen("sudo /home/username/src/myscript.sh", "r")) ) {
    while( !feof($fp) ){
        $logline = fgets($fp);
        fwrite($fplog, $logline);
        fflush($fplog);
    }
    fclose($fp);
} else {
    /* error handling */;
}
```

Why is the output not streamed to `log.txt` during execution?

When I run `sudo ./myscript.sh` in the terminal, the output of `mybinary` is printed as expected while it's running. However, when I call `myscript` via php, all I get is `-- starting --`. The rest of the output will only be put out when `mybinary` has finished.

I've also tried redirecting stdout inside `myscript` with `&>` or `&> | tee` to the log file which yields the same results.

How can I get to the stdout of `mybinary` in this setup?

EDIT: Seems like `boost::log` was not flushing when not running in a terminal. I edited the post and title accordingly.

Comment: paste your bash script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/suggestions.

Comment: Is your web server user has the good rights to execute `sudo myscript.sh` command ? Also, add the absolute path to your script

Comment: @jetchisel shellcheck reports "No issues detected"

Comment: @arnaud valmary Yes, the www-data user is allowed to run this script as sudo. Also, the output is generated correctly - it's just not flushed during execution but only written after the execution ‍♂️

Comment: Sounds like `mybinary` is buffering when stdout is not a tty, which is common for many tools and languages. You can probably reproduce the problem in a terminal with `sudo ./myscript.sh | cat` .

Comment: `mybinary`  is using `boost::log::trivial` for the output, that's likely to be the root cause. I wasn't aware that `mybinary` even knows about where its stdout might or might not be redirected to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit:

boost::log will disable its default output stream whenever another one is active. To circumvent that, add a custom console log like so:

```
...
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>
...
boost::log::add_console_log(
    std::cout, /* use stdout */
    boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true); /* auto flush after each call */
```

### Original answer:

`mybinary` was using `boost::log::trivial` which - as I just learned - seems not to flush its output when it's not running in a terminal.

My solution was to write the output directly from within `mybinary`.

If anyone's also struggeling with `boost` logging, here's my solution:

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp> //necessary for boost::log::add_file_log
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp> //necessary for formating options (%TimeStamp%, ...)
#include <string>

void initLog(std::string &logFilePath) {
    boost::log::add_common_attributes(); //init %TimeStamp%, etc
    if (!logFilePath.empty()) {
        boost::log::add_file_log(
            boost::log::keywords::file_name = logFilePath.c_str(),
            boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true, /* flush after each call */
            boost::log::keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%] [%Severity%]: %Message%"
        );
    }
#ifndef NDEBUG
   boost::log::core::get()->set_filter(boost::log::trivial::severity >= boost::log::trivial::debug);
#else
   boost::log::core::get()->set_filter(boost::log::trivial::severity >= boost::log::trivial::info);
#endif
}

int main() {
    std::string logFilePath;
    if (argc > 1) {
       logFilePath = argv[1];
    }

    initLog(logFilePath);

    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Running mybinary with logFile: " << logFilePath;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```